# Android Auto binds a list of MediaItem with subtitle

Tags: java, android, spotify, android-auto, mediaplayerservices

[image]

Have you ever try to add a tag like that.

First i thought it is an ImageSpan which is built by SpannableString then set to builder.setTitle(input: Charsequence).
I already tried but not working.

Do you guys know how Spotify can do that? or am i missing something, pls correct me.
Big thank

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something you put into the title, artist or other field, but an explicit flag you can example on each item.

As explained in the [Display additional metadata indicators for Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#metadata-indicators):

> The following constants can be used in both MediaItem description extras and MediaMetadata extras:
>
> - [`METADATA_KEY_IS_EXPLICIT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/utils/MediaConstants#METADATA_KEY_IS_EXPLICIT()): indicates whether the item contains explicit content. To indicate an item is explicit, use this constant as the key and the long [`METADATA_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_PRESENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/utils/MediaConstants#METADATA_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_PRESENT()) as the value.

They go on to use an example:

```
val extras = Bundle()
extras.putLong(
    MediaConstants.METADATA_KEY_IS_EXPLICIT,
    MediaConstants.METADATA_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_PRESENT)
// Add in other extras
val description =
    MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
        .setMediaId(/*...*/)
        .setTitle(resources.getString(/*...*/))
        .setExtras(extras)
        .build()
return MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(description, /* flags */)
```

Comment: Thanks! You got my idea. Seemly we cannot custom another our "icon" tag, must use default one